# Rgb image to the grayscale image

Tags: python, image, rgb, grayscale

I have an image of a laser beam in RGB format. I want to get the brightness of an image by converting it to grayscale.

But it turns out not what I planned. The center should be the brightest place, but it turns out dark
help, who knows

[image]

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import math

image = Image.open("/content/TiSa_fs_vert_1.jpg")
image = image.convert ('RGB')
width, height = image.size
y = 450

brightness_values = []

# Loop through the horizontal line
for x in range(width):
    pixelRGB = image.getpixel((x, y))
    R, G, B = pixelRGB
    #brightness = math.sqrt(R**2 + G**2 + B**2)
    brightness = (R + G + B)//3
    brightness_values.append(brightness)

print(brightness_values)
```

Comment: You may have more success with another mode, e.g. `L` (only one channel, already greyscale) or `HSV` (3 channels, Hue, Saturation, Value). Basically your gradient goes from the HSV hue component 0 (red) to around 225 (dark blue). See [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) for more information about the modes.

Comment: This seems to start with a wrong assumption: "The center should be the brightest place". The pure red, pure green, and pure blue (255 0 0, 0 255 0, 0 0 255) all seem present in your first picture, and would all have a brightness of 85 according to your formula.

Comment: It is unclear what your 2 images represent. Why have you got two? Which one is closest to the original data from your sensor and which has been processed? How?

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck since you're using a laser, it'll be monochrome and easy to seperate out from color channels

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import cv2

img = np.array(Image.open("laser.jpg"))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
# Since the laser is red, you can just take out the red channel from the RGB
# Color channels are 0=Red, 1=Green, 2=Blue
r=img[:,:,0]
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(r, cmap='grey') 
plt.show()

# To plot only the brightest portion of your selected channel, you can do:
threshold= r.max()*0.9
# set areas of the image that are below the threshold to be 0
r[np.where(r<threshold)]=0
# set areas of the image that are at or above the threshold to be 1
r[np.where(r>=threshold)]=1

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(r, cmap='grey')
plt.show()

# To clean up the image a bit more
cleaned_up = cv2.dilate(r,np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.uint8),iterations = 5)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(cleaned_up, cmap='grey')
plt.show()

# Simplistic method to calculate center
# (you should probably apply some smoothing to the calculated brightness along each axis)
x_sum = cleaned_up.sum(axis=0)
y_sum = cleaned_up.sum(axis=1)
center = (x_sum.max(), y_sum.max())
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(x_sum.shape[0]),x_sum)
plt.plot(y_sum,np.arange(y_sum.shape[0]))
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(cleaned_up, cmap='grey')
plt.plot(center[0],center[1], 'ro')
plt.show()

# Using image moments to find the centroid
moments = cv2.moments(cleaned_up)
centroid = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(cleaned_up, cmap='grey')
plt.plot(centroid[0],centroid[1], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

to be perfectly honest both methods for finding the center work decently well and produce very similar results, but I prefer the centroid approach using image moments as it looks more centered to my eyes, but feel free to pick the one that works the best for you

Comment: thanks for your reply! They helped a lot.

a friend who works in Matlab advised me to convert the image to an index image + first use the “jet” color map, and then convert it to grayscale (in Matlab it’s rgb2ind)
Is this possible to do in Python?

Comment: and if you use this solution and plot the intensity along the x and y axes, then the graph has a plateau, that is, it looks more like a super-Gaussian. but most likely it should be something like Gaussian

Comment: the problem stems from the fact that I'm taking pure red but your laser isn't likely to be pure red. You can calculate a weighted average of R,G and B channels (normal grayscale is `0.299 ∙ Red + 0.587 ∙ Green + 0.114 ∙ Blue` which is why it shows the center of the image as being "dark" since there isn't much green there. unless you provide more details on the exact wavelength of your laser and the expected "center" position, I can't help more.

Comment: I'm also not sure about what an "Indexed image" is, but any image processing is possible in any language, you just need to know the formulas and algorithms you need to use.

Comment: @ДмитрийКиселев To be honest both the green and blue channels are almost 0 in your area of interest so my previous comment doesn't work too well, but some thresholding helps out a lot, see the updated code and let me know if it solves your problem.